# MongoDB index suggestion tool

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Is there a tool that reads MongoDB `db.system.profile` data, query `.explain()` outputs, current `.getIndexes()` and any other information. Then outputs suggestions for missing indexes, or a list of unused indexes to remove?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate consideration would be to set notablescan to true in the configuration so that any query that required a table scan (I.e. didn't have appropriate indexes) wouldn't run.

It won't make suggestions for you but it will make sure you aren't missing anything.

Comment: Do aware you should not use this production, just in testing and development. As it notablescan will stop queries in all DB.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is pretty new database and i never seen such tools, and in general you should care about indexes yourself, because sometimes you need think more on a query, get rid some fields from compound indexes to speed up query, or even redesign database to achieve best performance. I don't think that there is any tool that can do it better then human.

You can simple enable profiler and see slow queries, if you don't like mongodb shell you can chose any mongodb management tool from available list [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).